# PL/SQL How to select and update type IS TABLE OF

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have the following need:
Insert and update in a type IS TABLE OF, the insert is correct, but now I need that before inserting, check if there is already a record to update, otherwise insert.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FLUXO_OBJ IS OBJECT (
     DT_VENC CHAR(10),
     TYPE CHAR(2),
     VALOR NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FLUXO_TAB IS TABLE OF FLUXO_OBJ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_FLUXO (
     P_DATE1 TABLE1.DT_VENC%TYPE, 
     P_DATE2 TABLE1.DT_VENC%TYPE) 
     RETURN FLUXO_TAB IS
 
   v_COUNT INTEGER; v_FLUXO INTEGER := 0; v_VALOR NUMBER := 0;
   v_VENC VARCHAR2(10); v_TYPE VARCHAR2(2); 
   v_SCRIPT VARCHAR2(100); v_SELECT SYS_REFCURSOR;
   v_FLUXO_OBJ FLUXO_TAB := FLUXO_TAB();
 
BEGIN
      v_SCRIPT := 'SELECT DT_VENC, TYPE, VALOR FROM TABLE1';
      BEGIN
         OPEN v_SELECT FOR v_SCRIPT;
         LOOP
            FETCH v_SELECT INTO v_VENC, v_TYPE, v_VALOR;
                  EXIT WHEN v_SELECT%NOTFOUND;
            BEGIN
                  BEGIN
                    /* HERE PROBLEM 1 */
                     SELECT COUNT(*)
                       INTO v_COUNT
                       FROM ??????
                      WHERE DT_VENC = v_VENC 
                        AND TYPE = v_TYPE;
                  END;
                  IF v_COUNT = 0 THEN /* INSERT */
                     v_FLUXO := v_FLUXO + 1;
                     v_FLUXO_OBJ.EXTEND;
                     v_FLUXO_OBJ(v_FLUXO) := FLUXO_OBJ(v_VENC,                                                           v_TYPE,v_VALOR);
                  ELSE
                    /* HERE PROBLEM 2 */
                     UPDATE ????
                        SET VALOR = VALOR + v_VALOR
                      WHERE DT_VENC = v_VENC
                        AND TYPE = v_TYPE;
                      ...
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem where you are constrained somehow in what you're writing?  Or real code?  If it's real code, I'm not sure why you're using dynamic SQL.  It doesn't make sense to use a `select` statement to get the number of elements in a collection when that collection has a `count` attribute.  It would make more sense to insert data into the collection by doing a `bulk collect`.  And I'm not sure why you'd want to do the `update` in a SQL statement rather than the more natural loop.

Comment: For Problem 1 you need the `table()` operator. For Problem 2 you need procedural code, as `update` can only be used with a database table or view.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO v_COUNT
FROM TABLE(v_FLUXO_OBJ)
WHERE DT_VENC = v_VENC
  AND TYPE = v_TYPE;

v_COUNT := v_FLUXO_OBJ.COUNT;   

v_COUNT := CARDINALITY(v_FLUXO_OBJ);
```

**UPDATE**

You cannot `UPDATE` a PL/SQL table, either use a loop and update one-by-one or do it like this:

```
 v_FLUXO_OBJ FLUXO_TAB := FLUXO_TAB();
 v_FLUXO_OBJ_updated FLUXO_TAB;

BEGIN

   SELECT FLUXO_OBJ(DT_VENC, TYPE, VALOR)
   BULK COLLECT INTO v_FLUXO_OBJ
   FROM TABLE1;

   SELECT FLUXO_OBJ(DT_VENC, TYPE, VALOR + 1)
   BULK COLLECT INTO v_FLUXO_OBJ_updated 
   FROM TABLE(v_FLUXO_OBJ);
```

Actually, when I have a closer look at your code, then a simple

```
SELECT FLUXO_OBJ(DT_VENC, TYPE, SUM(VALOR))
BULK COLLECT INTO v_FLUXO_OBJ
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY DT_VENC, TYPE;
```

should do all of it.

Comment: In both cases of syntax error:
Error(line,column): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(line,column): PLS-00103: Encountered the "end-of-file" symbol when one of the following symbols was expected: ;

Answer (score 1):

First solution:

```
SELECT ROWNUM
  INTO v_COUNT
  FROM TABLE(v_FLUXO_OBJ)
 WHERE DT_VENC = v_VENC
   AND TYPE = v_TYPE;
```

Second solution:

```
v_FLUXO_OBJ(v_COUNT).VALOR := v_FLUXO_OBJ(v_COUNT).VALOR + v_VALOR;
```